# Map Disappearing on HTML page when Sizing is changed from pixels (px) to percentages (%)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html, css

I am trying to allow this map to be resized via screen size (Mobile, Tablet, Chrome (Half Screen, Full Screen, etc.) so I know I can't set a specific pixel amount. However, when I do set a percentage the map disappears on my html page. I would like the map to have a height of 450px and a width of 600px at a maximum and then scale based on a screen size smaller then what can accommodate that.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Marketing Map</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/css/main.css">
<style>

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 450px; #I assume these need to be changed to 100% but the map disappears when I do this
  width: 600px; #I assume these need to be changed to 100% but the map disappears when I do this
}

#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 450px; #I assume these need to be changed to 100% but the map disappears when I do this
  width: 650px; #I assume these need to be changed to 100% but the map disappears when I do this
}
.esri-legend {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.9);
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 8px;
  max-width: 170px;
}
.esri-legend__layer-caption{
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
.esri-legend__layer-body{
  margin: 0px;
}
.esri-widget__heading {
  color: #ddd;
}

</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script>
<script>
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/Basemap",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/core/watchUtils",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
    "esri/layers/support/LabelClass",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/widgets/Home",
    "esri/widgets/DistanceMeasurement2D",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/widgets/LayerList",
    "esri/widgets/Expand",
    "esri/widgets/Legend",
    "dojo/query",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(Map,Basemap,MapView,watchUtils,FeatureLayer,MapImageLayer,LabelClass,Search,Home,DistanceMeasurement2D,BasemapGallery,LayerList,Expand,Legend,query,dom,on, mobile, parser, has, dTheme, registry){

    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "gray-vector"
    })
    var view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      center: [-77.11731019866023, 38.82010562165418],
      zoom:11,
      constraints: {
        maxZoom: 11,
        minZoom: 18
      }
    });

    const NbhRender = {
      type: "unique-value",
      field: "Constructi",
      defaulSymbol: {type: "simple-fill"},
      uniqueValueInfos: [{
        value: "Future Construction",
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-fill",
          color: "purple",
          outline: {
            width: 2,
            color: "white"
          }
        }
      }, {
        value: "In Construction",
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-fill",
          color: "red",
          outline: {
            width: 2,
            color: "white"
          }
        }
      }, {
        value: "Live",
        symbol: {
          type: "simple-fill",
          color: "#00aaee",
          outline: {
            width: 2,
            color: "white"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    };

    var nbhLyr = new FeatureLayer({
      url: "https://services8.arcgis.com/AH8GuAfnCoO6STfX/arcgis/rest/services/Alexandria_Boundaries/FeatureServer/0/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1",
      title: "Workzones",
      outFields: ["*"],
      renderer: NbhRender,
      visible: true,
      opacity: 0.3,
      visibleAtMapScale: true,
      minScale: 2000000,
      maxScale: 0
    });

    const nbhLabelClass = new LabelClass({
        labelExpressionInfo: { expression: "$feature.Name" },
        symbol: {
          type: "text",  // autocasts as new TextSymbol()
          color: "black",
          font: {
            weight: "bold",
            size: 10
          },
        }
      });

    nbhLyr.labelingInfo = [ nbhLabelClass ];

    map.add(nbhLyr)

    //add legend
    const legend = new Legend({
      view: view,
      visible: true,
      font: {
        size: 1
      },
      layerInfos: [{
        layer: nbhLyr,
        title: "Construction Status"
      }]
    });

    view.ui.add(legend,"bottom-left");
  });
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-98819163-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to add a div in the body that would hold the px amount and have the % amount in the viewDiv and multiple other approaches but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the height and width values to `100%`. It works fine when you do that:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/jumuyuhace/2/edit?html,output

[image]